# @_exported import in swift, to merge 2 frameworks

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

I have framework A, dependent on static library B. Both A and B have some public API I want to expose. I'm trying to mask the B public API as part of A, using `@_exported import B` inside A source files.

But after building and distributing the framework, when including it in a client project, I get the error "*Cannot find module B*" when I import A. Is `@_exported import` supposed to work this way or have I misunderstood.

Example framework project setup [here](https://github.com/sirghi/export-import).